# Checking mime type in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem with mime type checking of my `Resource`, I do it like below:

```
        Resource fileResource;

///

        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(model.getFileResource().getInputStream());

        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(model.getFileResource().getFile()));
        String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
```

and everything is ok when my `fileResource` is an jpeg/jpg file, then my `mimeType` is set to `image/jpeg`, but problem is when i upload pdf file, then my `mimeType` is `null`,

can someone tell me why?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

1. Add tika-core dependency. For example in Maven:

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
     <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.18</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. In you code:

   ```
   import org.apache.tika.Tika;

   Tika tika = new Tika();
   String mimeType = tika.detect(is);
   ```

Comment: In typical spring application, you would create bean for tika autowire in service and use.